# Adding Multiple addViews in a TableRow

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, textview

I've been searching for several hours now on this problem. I am trying to make a table with multiple values in a row in Android Studio. However, I don't want to hardcode the "cells" in, so I am trying to use Java to dynamically create the table rows and cells. Unfortunatly, when I try to add the cells in, it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3770)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3623)
at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3568)
at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3544)
at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:402)
at com.abukatech.tabletest2.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.java:32)
at com.abukatech.tabletest2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:20)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.abukatech.tabletest2.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/tabletest">
</TableLayout>
```

And here is my Java:

```
package com.abukatech.tabletest2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            test();
        }
    });
}

String[] test = {"buff", "meh", "plz!"};
public void test() {
    TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabletest);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        TextView testview = new TextView(this);
        testview.setText(test[i]);
        // I think this is where my problem is
        tbl.addView(testview);
        tbl.addView(testview);
    }
}
```

}

I've also been hearing about "inflating" TextView, but couldn't find any information on it. If you know about it, or if there's a better way to add a TextView dynamically to a a TableRow, please tell me, as I am a complete Java noob. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your code is correct except for the part where you add TextViews to the TableLayout. The problem is that the you're adding the same TextView object twice. This causes the exception you're seeing.

Remove the second `tbl.addView(testview)` call and your code should be fine.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that would do the trick, but what I want to do is make each row have more than one TextView without declaring a different TextView for each cell (because that would be wasteful). Do you know how that could be done?

Comment: @Mister_Maybe what you're saying can't be done because you can't use the same view instance in two places anywhere in your view hierarchy. Even at a domain level one View object represents just one View and cannot represent more than one View.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to create a new TextView every time a for loop iterates, add a unique value to it, and then add _that_ view to the table? Sorry if I'm asking too much lol :)

Comment: Your code is currently doing that. You're creating a new TextView on each loop iteration and adding it. Perhaps you mean to do something else, please clarify?

Comment: What I mean is that it adds it to all the other TextViews without overwriting them. So with each iteration, the amout of cells increase. It would look like this:                                                                                   Iteration 1: (table cell) Iteration 2: (table cell)(new table cell added to other table cell in row) Iteration 3: (table cell)(table cell)(another new table cell) etc. Then after a certain number of iterations, it would add a new row, and add table cells there. So the final result would be: (table cell)(table cell)(table cell) NEW ROW (table cell) etc...

Comment: @Mister_Maybe that is the default behaviour of the TableLayout. If you want to control the number of cells  per row you can set that with the TableLayout APIs. If you want to manually add new rows you can add TableRow objects to your TableView and add your TextViews to the TableRow object per iteration.